# Editing OpenCL in netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, ide, opencl

I recently read a question on IDE's here on StackOverflow, having always been an emacs user I decided to try out one of these ide's, namely netbeans for editing C++. It was so nice that I got a little carried away and wanted to edit OpenCL files in it to.

And now for my question. I have netbeans set up to process the opencl source files like C files but this causes a problem. The __kernel keyword makes the syntax checker act really strange.

Does anyone know how to make netbeans ignore a keyword in a specific(*.cl) file?

The following solution looks like its working:

```
#ifndef tan
#define __kernel
#define __global
#define __local
#define __private
#define get_global_id
#define get_global_size
#define get_local_id
#define get_local_size
#define barrier
#endif
```

Since tan is defined without a header, netbeans does not see it, and the keywords are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the answer you want, but for temporary editing, just put lines like

```
#define __kernel
#define __global
#define __local
#define __private
```

at the beginning of the cl file. This is working in Eclipse. I think it will work in Netbeans, too.

Drawback: You need pay attention to remove the `#define` statements, otherwise the code will not work.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make netbeans ignore a keyword, you could define `ONLY_DEFINED_IN_NETBEANS` in the preprocessor definitions entry in the code assistence options of the project, while not defining it elsewhere. Your code can then be modified as

```
#ifdef ONLY_DEFINED_IN_NETBEANS
#define __kernel
#define __global
#define __local
#define __private
#define get_global_id
#define get_global_size
#define get_local_id
#define get_local_size
#define barrier
#endif
```

The netbeans parser will ignore these keywords.

The same trick can be applied as a patch to the bug reported in netbeans on the `__restrict__` keyword:

```
#ifdef ONLY_DEFINED_IN_NETBEANS
#define __restrict__
#define restrict
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

you can tell the C editor of netbeans to entirely ignore syntax errors but i don't think that you will have luck to teach netbeans the CL specific keywords.

tools->options->C++->build tools

- duplicate the tool config
- give it a name and remove all paths to the compiler
- make it default

tools->options->C++->highlighting

- uncheck highlight syntax errors and unresolved identifiers